# PAR2 lib for Java

Tags: java, par

I am searching for a PAR2 library to be used in a custom Java application. It seems the only lib available on sourceforge (JPar2) is in planning status since 2008, no update since then. Any of guys had better luck?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're talking about [Parchive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive#Version_2), right?

Comment: yes, file integrity checking, used in Usenet

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I have decided to use [zfec library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zfec), it is extremely easy to use, no need to even read anything. All you need is zfec --help and you're done.

Check out my answer in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818211/reed-solomon-java-library-partitioning-files-with-redundancy).

> In order to communicate with Java I'm considering two possibilities:
>
> 1. Create a JNI.
> 2. Create a small local HTTP service in python as a wrapper of the zfec library. Probably with some like Flask

JPar2 is still not available as of today. (february 2014)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will have a look at zfec.

Comment: I forgot to add the link @Matthias the command line execution is extremely simple.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have decided to go with a Java implementation of the FEC.

It is based on [onion networks](https://bitbucket.org/onionnetworks/fec) FEC library.

I developed a wrapper for that library that hopefully makes it easier to use for what I need. It has Junit tests and a simpler API for creating the chunks from a File or from a byte array.

Take a look [here](https://bitbucket.org/jsanta/pay-with-bytes-jfec-wrapper/overview) if you are interested, it is a public repository in bitbucket.

Comment: I think this might help @Matthias, the python approach was to complicated.